# anonymous js function with xhrpost dojo not returning data

Tags: javascript, dojo

```
var cType = function(templateId){
        dojo.xhrPost({
            url : "/mediation1.0.1/template/getCollectorType",
            handleAs : "text",
            headers : {"Content-Type":"text/html"},
            postData : templateId,
            load: function(data){
                    return data;
            }});
    };
```

When I call this function with cType(withSomeId), I get undefined.
Even When I take local variable and assign data to that variable, returning thatvariable also not helping.

Comment: Have you tried to print the resposne on console in load

Comment: yes, It's printing correct within scope of xhrPost

Comment: dojo.xhrPost is an ajax (Asynchronous Javascript And XML) call. The function will quit before the result is resolved and the `load`-handler gets executed.

Comment: That means I have to attach call handler to this request and access data from that handler. This is what you are suggesting ?? @Andreas

Comment: BTW what are you trying to do from the data recvd? Why not the function use data and do the work required.

Comment: @ejb_guy : I wanto separate that part because I will be using that function at many places :(

Comment: Well you can invoke the function from within load and pass the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your cType function does not return anything.

```
var cType = function(templateId){
    dojo.xhrPost({
        url : "/mediation1.0.1/template/getCollectorType",
        handleAs : "text",
        headers : {"Content-Type":"text/html"},
        postData : templateId,
        load: function(data){
                return data; 
                // this returns from the the load 
                // function, not the cType function!
        }});

    // You are not returning anything from the cType function.
 };
```

You should be using `dojo.Deferred` to accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
var cType = function(templateId){
  var xhrArgs = {
        url : "/mediation1.0.1/template/getCollectorType",
        handleAs : "text",
        headers : {"Content-Type":"text/html"},
        postData : templateId
  };

  return dojo.xhrGet(xhrArgs);
};

var deferred = cType('templateId');
deferred.then(
  function(data){
      // do something with the data...
  },
  function(error){
      // handle an error calling the server...
  }
);
```

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/xhrGet.html (This has an example that shows the deferred technique)

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/xhrPost.html

Comment: working like charm. Just add return statement in cType i.e. return dojo.xhrGet(xhrArgs);